# Site published by WCF publishing wizard throws "Error in the application.."

Tags: wcf, iis-7.5, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2

I'm running BizTalk 2013r2 and run into a problem with the publishing wizard.

I have used the BizTalk WCF publish wizard, following the the steps:

Metadata only endpoint (MEX), publish for receive location 
Publish schemas as a WCF service
Update the web service description tree view to give a single one-way web method
Give a target namespace (currently using http://tempuri.org/)
Enter location for website (is use localhost), select Overwrite existing location, Allow anonymous access
Generated service summary is below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<WcfServiceDescription xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Name="BizTalkWcfService" TargetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2006/01/Adapter/Wcf/Publishing">
  <LocationSettings Location="http://localhost/BTS-Store6" Overwrite="true" AuthAnonymous="true" />
  <ApplicationSettings CreateReceiveLocations="false" ApplicationName="" />
  <AdapterSettings AdapterName="" />
  <MetadataSettings EnableMetadata="false" MetadataOnly="true" ReceiveLocationName="RcvStore6POS_WCF" />
  <WcfServices>
    <WcfService Name="OnRamp">
      <WcfOperations>
        <WcfOperation Name="POSTransaction" Flow="OneWay">
          <WcfMessages>
            <WcfMessage Name="Request" Direction="Input">
              <WcfMessageType Category="XsdType" TypeName="BTS.GO.Store6.Schemas.BT.POSTranaction" AssemblyName="BTS.GO.Core.Store6.Schemas, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=0a9764041befeb8b" AssemblyLocation="C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\BTS.GO.Core.Store6.Schemas\v4.0_1.0.0.0__0a9764041befeb8b\BTS.GO.Core.Store6.Schemas.dll" TargetNamespace="http://BTE.ESB.StoreInputModel.POSTransaction" RootName="POS" IsAnyType="false" IsEnvelope="false" />
            </WcfMessage>
          </WcfMessages>
        </WcfOperation>
      </WcfOperations>
    </WcfService>
  </WcfServices>
</WcfServiceDescription>
```

Problem is, after publish the site, I can browse to the .svc, and use WCF storm to consume the WSD - all is good. However, after leaving it for about 30 minutes - when I next try to access the service the following error is thrown:

```
<Event xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/win/2004/08/events/event">
    <System>
      <Provider Name="System.ServiceModel 4.0.0.0"/>
      <EventIDQualifiers="49154">3</EventID>
      <Level>2</Level>
      <Task>5</Task>
      <Keywords>0x80000000000000</Keywords>
      <TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-01-12T12:26:41.000000000Z"/>
      <EventRecordID>293995</EventRecordID>
      <Channel>Application</Channel>
      <Computer>000alien004.gooutdoors.local</Computer>
      <Security UserID="S-1-5-21-1638455640-2704731959-1606034848-1010"/>
    </System>
    <EventData>
      <Data>System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult/11812267</Data>
      <Data>System.ServiceModel.ServiceActivationException: The service '/BTS-Store6/OnRamp.svc' cannot be activated due to an exception during compilation. The exception message is: Error in the application.. ---> System.ApplicationException: Error in the application. at System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ThrowExceptionForHRInternal(Int32 errorCode, IntPtr errorInfo) at System.Management.ManagementObjectCollection.ManagementObjectEnumerator.MoveNext() at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Metadata.ConfigurationInfo.GetReceiveLocation(String receiveLocationName) at Microsoft.BizTalk.Adapter.Wcf.Metadata.MexServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String constructorString, Uri[] baseAddresses) at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.CreateService(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.ActivateService(ServiceActivationInfo serviceActivationInfo, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) at System.ServiceModel.ServiceHostingEnvironment.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String normalizedVirtualPath, EventTraceActivity eventTraceActivity) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End[TAsyncResult](IAsyncResult result) at System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult result)</Data>
      <Data>w3wp</Data>
      <Data>21772</Data>
    </EventData>
</Event>
```

With an exception message as vague as "Error in the application.." I'm at a loss as to what may be causing this. I have tried this many times. Usually, but not always, after republishing the site from the wizard I am able to browse to the service. The later, with semmingly only elapsed time being a changing factor, it fails.

Any ideas?

Comment: It seems It is not able to find the receive location. How do you fix this by republishing? Or you need to recycle IIS app pool?

Comment: recycle app pool has no impact, I need to re-publish each time

Comment: When you get this error, can you look at the folder your virtual directory points to, looks some thing changes in there which causes compilation to fail.

Comment: The only content is what's published by the "BizTalk WCF Service Publishing Wizard"

Comment: What happens if you continuously use or ping the service every few minutes?  Does it still die after half an hour?  What happens if you restart IIS (iisreset.exe) after it dies?  Does it come back or do you still have to republish? Could be some kind of timeout issue.